# PHP: web socket connections

Tags: php, sockets, rest, http, websocket

I was wondering if I can serve an app chat using PHP socket. My question is: **how many socket connections can PHP handle?** I'm using Amazon AWS instance, currently my chat uses HTTP GET requests to retrieve updates, but it is slow and uses unnecessary resources.

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP capability to handle multiple TCP connections?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12605294/php-capability-to-handle-multiple-tcp-connections)